# Changing the Database to pg from sql for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, heroku

I always start my new rails applications with rails new app_name which defaults to the sql database language. I am wondering three things:

1. Is there a way to default the database language to pg whenever creating an app?
2. How do I change an application from sql to pg once its been created? I tried changing the database language in the gem file, and typically receive this error:

   ```
   $ gem install pg -v '0.18.4'

   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   ERROR:  Error installing pg:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       current directory: /Users/eric.park/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
   /Users/eric.park/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160125-86030-51pvqj.rb extconf.rb
   checking for pg_config... no
   No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
    --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
   checking for libpq-fe.h... no
   Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
   need configuration options.

   Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/Users/eric.park/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
       --with-pg
       --without-pg
       --enable-windows-cross
       --disable-windows-cross
       --with-pg-config
       --without-pg-config
       --with-pg_config
       --without-pg_config
       --with-pg-dir
       --without-pg-dir
       --with-pg-include
       --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
       --with-pg-lib
       --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

   To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

     /Users/eric.park/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log

   extconf failed, exit code 1

   Gem files will remain installed in /Users/eric.park/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
   Results logged to /Users/eric.park/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
   ```

Finally, where is sql just not supported by Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the error you are getting is because you need the `postgresql` development tools.

For Mac: `brew install postgresql`
For Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`
For Fedora: `sudo yum install postgresql-devel` or `sudo dnf install postgresql-devel`

Secondly, Heroku supports `MySQL` of course but `PostgreSQL` is free of charge.